# Ocultar valores duplicados SQL

Tags: php, sql

Bom, estou fazendo um projeto pequeno de processo de aprovação. Preciso consultar duas tabelas com dados que podem ser iguais, mas preciso que esse dados iguais **não apareçam**, no caso fiquem ocultos.

**Exemplo:**

> ```
> TABELA1         TABELA2
>  Col1            Col2
>    1               1
>    2               4
>    3               5
> ```

Precisava que ele retorne um *SELECT* **sem exibir** os valores duplicados.

Comment: Favor colocar a resposta esperada para o exemplo acima de forma a dirimir as dúvidas dos que querem ajuda-lo.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `UNION`:

```
SELECT t1.campo1 FROM tabela1 t1
UNION
SELECT t2.campo2 FROM tabela2 t2
```

Answer (score 1):

O importante é entender o que ocorre na consulta. O UNION faz a união de dois resultados retirando as duplicidades.

Lembro que o UNION vai levar em consideração todas as colunas de retorno da consulta.
Assim, a consulta via UNION vai trazer um campo apenas de resultado com Ids distintos.

Já o comando citado acima (representado abaixo) vai fazer uma projeção entre as duas tabelas e somente vai relacionar os itens da tabela 1 que não conteém id = na tabela 2:

```
SELECT * FROM #t1 tabela1 CROSS JOIN #t2 tabela2 WHERE (tabela1.id <> tabela2.id);
```

O retorno da consulta acima, assumindo seus dados de exemplo seria algo como:

```
   id tb1  id tb2
    1        4
    1        5
    2        1
    2        4
    2        5
    3        1
    3        4
    3        5
```

O id 1 da tabela1 somente projetou com os id's diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta a expressão SQL seria:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 CROSS JOIN tabela2 WHERE (tabela1.col1 <> tabela2.col2);
```